# Deleting groups of countries from World Development Index Data

Tags: r, dplyr

I am brand new to R. I am using the World Development Index Dataset and am trying to remove all region rows such as Sub-Saharan Africa (IDA & IBRD countries) or Middle East & North Africa (IDA & IBRD countries). I want to create a dataframe with the countries only. Thank you!

```
library(WDI)

WDI.data <-WDI(country="all", indicator=c("IQ.CPA.GNDR.XQ",
        "SP.DYN.CBRT.IN", "AG.LND.AGRI.K2", "AG.LND.AGRI.ZS"), start=1995, end=2005)

FilteredWDI <- WDI.data %>% 
  filter(WDI.data$iso2c == ???)
```

Comment: which exactly are the countries you want to remove? you need to list of them..

Comment: Hello, I only want to view the (all) countries. I want to remove all rows of groups of countries (e.g. "Arab World," "Europe & Central Asia (excluding high income),"East Asia & Pacific (IDA & IBRD countries)," etc.).

Comment: okay, i'll update my answer. i just found a way to exclude it.

Comment: well, i think i achieved what you need.. check it out!

Comment: Tagged with WDI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `countrycode` package to create a region variable and then filter based on that:

```r
    library(countrycode)
    library(tidyverse)
    WDI.data %>% 
      as_tibble() %>%
      mutate(region = countrycode(iso2c, "iso2c", "region")) %>% 
      filter(!region %in% c("Sub-Saharan Africa", "Middle East & North Africa"), 
             !is.na(region))
```

The `!is.na(region)` will also throw out throw out regional (as opposed to country) observations, which you probably also want to get rid of.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow NelCap.

To solve your problem you have to realize that the `iso2c` of regions are composed of a character and a number, while the `iso2c` of countries are composed only of characters. Therefore, you have to track all the `iso2c` containing at least one number and remove these rows, as follows:

```
library(WDI)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

WDI.data <-WDI(country="all", indicator=c("IQ.CPA.GNDR.XQ",
                                          "SP.DYN.CBRT.IN", "AG.LND.AGRI.K2", "AG.LND.AGRI.ZS"), start=1995, end=2005)

FilteredWDI <- WDI.data %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(iso2c, '\\d'))
```

Note that the `!` is a reserved sign in **R**, it stands for negations.

I hope it helped you.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!

Comment: that's great @NelCap. remember it's a good practice to vote for the answers that helped you..

Comment: Thanks! It looks like upvotes from users with less than 15 rep are recorded but do not changed the displayed score.

Answer (score 1):

The following code filters out all `IDA` and `IBRD` countries based on the built-in data set `WDI_data`. This data is a list of two matrices, we want matrix `WDI_data$country`, columns `"country"` and `"lending"`.

```
library(WDI)
library(dplyr)

WDI.data <- WDI(country = "all", 
                indicator = c(
                  "IQ.CPA.GNDR.XQ",
                  "SP.DYN.CBRT.IN", 
                  "AG.LND.AGRI.K2", 
                  "AG.LND.AGRI.ZS"
                ), 
                start = 1995, end = 2005)

FilteredWDI <- WDI.data %>%
  inner_join(as.data.frame(WDI_data$country[, c("country", "lending")]), by = "country") %>%
  filter(!lending %in% c("IDA", "IBRD"))
```